# TSQL - Merge two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a following task: I have two single column tables in a procedure and both of them have the same amount of rows. I'd like to "merge" them so I get a resulting table with 2 columns. I there some easy way for this?

In worst case I could try to add primary key and use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with `JOIN` but it requires quite big changes in the code I already have so I decided to ask you guys.

Just to explain my answer below, here's the example. I have following tables:

```
tableA
col1
----
1
2
3
4

tableB
col2
----
a
b
c
d

Resulting table:
col1 | col2
1    | a
2    | b
3    | c
4    | d
```

Comment: Just to explain my answer below. I have following tables:

Comment: In general collection terms, this is a "zip" of the two collections.  (Think of this like the zipper on your jacket, not a compressed file.)  The .NET and Ruby implementations of this concept are even called "Zip".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col1 AS col2
INTO NewTable
FROM
(
   SELECT col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RN
   FROM table1
) AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RN
   FROM table2
) AS t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn
```

This will create a brand new table `NewTable` with the two columns from the two tables:

```
| COL1 | COL2 |
---------------
|    1 |    a |
|    2 |    b |
|    3 |    c |
|    4 |    d |
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9749f/1)

Comment: Not really. They don't have straight forward relation (both have just one column with different values) but I know that first row relates with first row, second with second and so on. I know that it's easy with CURSOR or WHILE loop but because of effectiveness I cannot use it. As for the JOIN I would need to add primary key column which I'd like to avoid...

Comment: @Moby04 - OK, sorry. See my edit. Assuming that they have the same number of rows.

Comment: I'll check this out right in the morning but seems promising. Thanks :)